# powerbi embeded in .net core 1.1

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, powerbi, visual-studio-2017, powerbi-embedded

Currently, I am trying to import powerbi packages in visual studio 2017 for my .net core 1.1 project. However, I get the following error:

```
Install-Package : Package Microsoft.PowerBI.Core 1.1.10 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1). Package Microsoft.PowerBI.Core 1.1.10 supports: net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5)At line:1 char:1
```

Has this happened to anybody else? Do you know how to work around this and embed powerbi in the new .net core 1.1? I tried to search a lot of places but because of the constant changes, I do get outdated information. Thanks!

Comment: From nuget https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.PowerBI.Core/ it doesn't seem to support NETstandard or win8+net45 PCL, so short answer is: You can't use it. use ASP.NET Core with .NET Framework 4.5 instead

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and ported the api to netstandard, see if it helps:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/PowerBI.NetStandard.Api/1.0.0